# val_loss increase while val_acc keep in 60% with the pre_training model inception_v3

Tags: python, keras

My code:

```
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
train_data_dir = 'newdata64/train'
validation_data_dir = 'newdata64/validation'
nb_train_samples =1500
nb_validation_samples = 948
epochs = 1000
batch_size = 10

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', 
include_top=False,input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3))
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

x = Dropout(0.8)(x)

x = Dense(2)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.00001, momentum=0.4), 
loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: acc-epoch]

[image: loss-epoch]

I have tried image generator to make data argumentation, add dropout(0.5),add BN after FC layer,but the `val_loss` becoming increasing whereas the loss become descent,and the `cal_acc`　seem to keep in a value not to increase while acc going to 100%.
I just have few data (1500train data ,948validation data).
Is there any solution to such problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is a clear overfit. The training set is perfectly learnt but the model doesn't work on test data.

Given that you have used a high dropout rate, it might be that your data is not split correctly between the training set and the validation set. It is possible that you have very different data in the two datasets!

It is very difficult to help you because we have no insights on what  you are trying to predict and how the dataset looks like. You have not many examples at all in your datasets.